# XSL output array of string as text

Tags: arrays, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0, xpath-3.1

I am trying to create an array and append few values to it and output the transformed text by iterating over this array. But the output is ignoring the content of xsl:text.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template name="test" match="/">
        <xsl:param name="data" select="data"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:variable name="myData" select="$data" />

        <xsl:variable name="myArray" as="array(xs:string)">
            <xsl:sequence select="array{}" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="array:append($myArray, 'John')" />
        <xsl:sequence select="array:append($myArray, 'Peter')" />

        <xsl:for-each select="1 to array:size($myArray)">
            <xsl:text>Person name is : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="array:get($myArray,.)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This output as

```
["John"]
["Peter"]
```

While I was expecting

```
Person name is : John
Person name is : Peter
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but the output I get using your code is not what you report: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5EJTn

Comment: Note also, that doing e.g. `<xsl:variable name="myArray" as="array(xs:string)" select="['John', 'Peter']"/>` would suffice to populate an array statically, as would e.g. `array { 'John', 'Peter' }`, and the curly braces array "constructor" expression can take any sequence (assuming in the real use case you want to populate the array from a sequence of values dynamically).

Comment: There is a more general solution using a single XPath expression that dynamically populates an array with the results of processing of each input member ( item() or item()* )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the main problem with your attempt is that the instruction:

```
<xsl:sequence select="array:append($myArray, 'John')" />
```

does not modify the `$myArray` variable. It merely writes to the output the result of appending a member to the (empty) array in `$myArray`, while the size of the array itself remains 0.

If instead you use:

```
<xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array:append($myArray, 'John')" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array:append($myArray, 'Peter')" />
```

you should get the result you seek.

---

BTW, you can shorten:

```
    <xsl:variable name="myArray" as="array(xs:string)">
        <xsl:sequence select="array{}" />
    </xsl:variable>
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array{}"/>
```

---

P.S. A purist will tell you that in my suggestion the original `$myArray` variable is also not being modified; it is only [shadowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#scope-of-variables) by binding another value to the same name.

Comment: Thanks @michael. This has fixed the output I was trying to get but I have actually tried to append the array by iterating in for-each block but that doesn't seem to append any values. Do you have any suggestion to iterate and add them to array like    <xsl:for-each select="1 to array:size($myData)">
        <xsl:variable name="personName" select="array:get($myData, .)" />
         <xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array:append($myArray, personName)" />
        </xsl:for-each>

Comment: Its like I'm having an array of objects which I will iterate and create a new array of Strings with values of my interest. And use these strings from new array to output at different place with different formatting. I thought it would be same as appending inside a for-each loop, which apparently isn't. What is the way around this. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you ask this as a separate question and provide an example that also shows the source of the data.

Comment: P.S. As already mentioned by Martin Honnen, `array { $sequence }` constructs an array whose members are the items in `$sequence` - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#array-functions

Comment: I have created a new question for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167409/xslt-create-new-array-iterating-over-an-existing-array

Answer (score 0):

This pure XPath expression does the wanted processing, **regardless of how many items must be put into the resulting array**.

Note that in the general case the function may do some processing of each input item and append to the array the result of this processing. Also, using this solution there is no need at all to define any `xsl:variable` to hold the array, and thus no shadowing and consuming unnecessary memory:

```
fold-left(("John", "Peter", "Kevin", "Ryan"), [], 
          function($accum as array(*), $inputItem)
          {
            array:append($accum, $inputItem)
          }
      )
```

**When the expression is evaluated the expected, correct result is produced**:

`["John","Peter","Kevin","Ryan"]`

---

**An example of processing each input item before placing it in the resulting array**:

```
fold-left(("John", "Peter", "Kevin", "Ryan"), [], 
          function($accum as array(*), $inputItem)
          {
            array:append($accum, string-length($inputItem))
          }
      )
```

**When the expression is evaluated the expected, correct result is produced**:

`[4,5,5,4]`

---

**With a long input, that is not suitable for manual array appends**, for example, produce the first `N` numbers with value `6 * k -  1`, where `k` varies from `1` to `N`:

```
fold-left((1 to 50), [], 
          function($accum as array(*), $inputItem)
          {
            array:append($accum, $inputItem * 6 -1)
          }
         )
```

**When the expression is evaluated the expected, correct result is produced**:

```
[5,11,17,23,29,35,41,47,53,59,65,71,77,83,89,95,101,107,113,119,125,131,137,143,149,155,161,167,173,179,185,191,197,203,209,215,221,227,233,239,245,251,257,263,269,275,281,287,293,299]
```