# XSLT create new array iterating over an existing array

Tags: java, arrays, xslt, saxon

I am trying to collect strings of my interest by iterating over an array of objects and create a new array. I would use this new array later in my transformation to generate the output.

Below is my code:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
        xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
        xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
        version="3.0">
        <xsl:output method="text"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
        <xsl:template name="test" match="/">
            <xsl:param name="data" select="data"></xsl:param>
            <xsl:variable name="myData" select="$data" />
    
          <xsl:variable name="inputArray" select="array{'John', 'Peter'}"/>
           <xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array{}"/>
          
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to array:size($inputArray)">
            <xsl:variable name="personName" select="array:get($inputArray, .)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$personName" />
             <xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array:append($myArray, personName)" />
            </xsl:for-each>
    <!--       <xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array:append($myArray, 'John')" />
          <xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array:append($myArray, 'Peter')" /> -->
          
          <xsl:for-each select="1 to array:size($myArray)">
          <xsl:value-of select="test" />
            <xsl:text>Person name is : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="array:get($myArray,.)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This doesn't append the values into myArray and doesn't even enter the for-each block to output the "test" string.

The source for input array is the array of objects as below:

```
  map {"persons": [map {
                    "name": "John",
                    "age": 33,
                    "residence":"Permanent" 
                    }, map {
                    
                    "name": "Peter",
                    "age": 36,
                    "residence":"Temporary"
                        }
            ]
    }
```

I would be reading this array using map:get($persons) iterate and collect the names into myArray.

Comment: This is somewhat confusing because the input array is already an array of strings - so what's the point of this exercise? The term "objects" is also too vague.

Comment: I have updated the question with kind of array I'm passing as input to iterate and create myArray of specific values i.e. names in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this input variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="input-map" select="
    map {'persons': 
        [ 
        map {
            'name': 'John',
            'age': 33,
            'residence':'Permanent' 
            }, 
        map {
            'name': 'Peter',
            'age': 36,
            'residence':'Temporary'
            }
        ]
    }"/>
```

you can create an array of names using:

```
<xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array{$input-map?persons?*?name}"/>
```

Comment: Do note that the result of querying the map is already a *sequence*, i.e. "an ordered collection of zero or more items". I am not sure what advantage is there to be gained by converting it to an array.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I accept this approach and this serves the purpose . I was just curious, instead of selecting all the names, what if I were to create an array of names whose residence type is 'Temporary'.

Comment: In such case you would get a sequence of `$input-map?persons?*[?residence='Temporary']?name`.

Comment: Is it an XPath expression? I'm aware of navigating inside a tree using "/" but not "?" can you please point me to further tutorials or references. Thank you

Comment: The specifications provide several alternative syntaxes for map lookup. Here is one:  https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-3/#id-map-lookup. The one I used above is described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-3/#id-lookup. And then there is the `map:get()` function described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-map-get. Note that both maps and arrays are a late addition to XPath/XSLT and their handling is a departure from the orthodox methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath 3.1, don't think in procedural terms like iteration, then you can just do e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="inputArray" select="array{'John', 'Peter'}"/>
<xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array{ $inputArray?* }"/>
```

We could also spell that out with `fold-left`, or, if you really wanted to "iterate", `xsl:iterate`, but I don't see any need for this.

The [whole stylesheet](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22text%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20name%3D%22test%22%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22inputArray%22%20select%3D%22array%7B%27John%27%2C%20%27Peter%27%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22myArray%22%20select%3D%22array%7B%20%24inputArray%3F*%20%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24myArray%3F*%20%21%20%28%27Person%20name%20is%3A%20%27%20%7C%7C%20.%29%22%20separator%3D%22%26%2310%3B%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Ctest%2F%3E&input-type=XML) could be e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">
  
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template name="test" match="/">
        
      <xsl:variable name="inputArray" select="array{'John', 'Peter'}"/>
      <xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array{ $inputArray?* }"/>
      
      <xsl:value-of select="$myArray?* ! ('Person name is: ' || .)" separator="&#10;"/>
      
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For processing the map, you still can use XPath 3.1 to construct the array based on the properties:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">
  
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template name="test" match="/">
        
      <xsl:variable name="inputObject" select='map {"persons": [map {
                    "name": "John",
                    "age": 33,
                    "residence":"Permanent" 
                    }, map {
                    
                    "name": "Peter",
                    "age": 36,
                    "residence":"Temporary"
                        }
            ]
    }'/>
      <xsl:variable name="myArray" select="array{ $inputObject?persons?*?name }"/>
      
      <xsl:value-of select="$myArray?* ! ('Person name is: ' || .)" separator="&#10;"/>
      
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin. Its not an apple to apple copy but I would be picking specific values from the object which I have updated in question. I need to iterate over this objects and store the names in new array.

Comment: @technocrat, there is no need for "iteration" to select values from an XDM/XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 map/array.